# Create Dictionary<Tuple<string>, Tuple<string, object>> for storing multiple json file names and data from different folders

Tags: c#, arrays, json, dictionary, json.net

Following below is the sample folder structure under a parent folder , there are sub directories and then files, I want to read and store them in a variable and use them for different methods but not successful.

Sample code :

```
  //Task<Dictionary<Tuple<string>, Tuple<string, object>>> a;
            Task<Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, object>>>> a;

            List<IListBlobItem> folders;
            try
            {
                CloudBlobContainer container = Retrier<CloudBlobContainer>.TryWithDelayIncremental(() => blobclient.GetContainerReference(ContainerName), NoOfRetries, DelayInMilliSecs);

                var blobs = container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: false, blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.None);
                folders = blobs.Where(b => b as CloudBlobDirectory != null).ToList();

                foreach (CloudBlobDirectory directory in folders)
                {
                    if (directory.Prefix == "initiatives/")
                    {
                        foreach (CloudBlobDirectory subDirectory in directory.ListBlobs())
                        {
                            foreach (IListBlobItem item in subDirectory.ListBlobs())
                            {
                                CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;

                                string name = blob.Name;
                                string[] split = name.Split('/');
                                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                                var policyData = blob.DownloadText();


                                a.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key,
                         pair => pair.Value.Select(tuple =>
                              tuple.Create(tuple.Item1,
                                           tuple.Item2,
                                           ConvertToEnum(tuple))).ToArray());
                                //create initiative assignment folder
                                // ManagementGroupClient mg = new ManagementGroupClient(Token);
                                //await mg.DeployPolicyToMG(split[2], policyData, split[1]);

                                // send the name of the initiative file , response 
                                Console.WriteLine(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

folder structure --

```
Parent folder -  sub directoryfolder  - files 
Initatives --     initative1          policy1.json
                                      policy2.json

                  initiative2        policy3.json
                                     policy4.json
```

I want to add into dictionary like for initiative1 folder i should add file name and file data and  initative2 folder the list of file name and file data and so on

Comment: Honestly, I think you'll tie yourself in knots with this convoluted data storage; it will take a few seconds to make a sensibly named class with sensibly named properties rather than having a TupleTupleTuple with Item1,2,7,99 all over the place...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @RufusL , I am looking for options to store the file to reuse and my question has the format of the folder structure but am not successful in creating using tuples

Comment: @CaiusJard , Could you please provide a sample example of code on how you are suggesting, that would really help me to understand deep dive